# How to count files inside a folder using PHP?

Tags: php, dir, subdirectory

The following code counts the number of files inside a folder.

```
<?php
function folderlist(){
  $directoryist = array();
$startdir = './';
//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
  $ignoredDirectory[] = '.';
  $ignoredDirectory[] = '..';
   if (is_dir($startdir)){
       if ($dh = opendir($startdir)){
           while (($folder = readdir($dh)) !== false){
               if (!(array_search($folder,$ignoredDirectory) > -1)){
                 if (filetype($startdir . $folder) == "dir"){
                       $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['name'] = $folder;
                       $directorylist[$startdir . $folder]['path'] = $startdir;
                   }
               }
           }
           closedir($dh);
       }
   }
return($directorylist);
}


$folders = folderlist();

$total_files = 0;
foreach ($folders as $folder){
    $path = $folder['path'];
    $name = $folder['name'];
    $count = iterator_count(new DirectoryIterator($path . $name));
    $total_files += $count;

    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' .$path .'index.php?album=' .$name . '" class="style1">';
    echo '<strong>' . $name . '</strong>';
    echo ' (' . $count . ' files found)';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
}
  echo "Total Files:". $total_files;
?>
```

However for some reason the count is off by 2. I have a folder with 13 files but this code returns count as 15. For an empty folder, this returns a count of 2.

Can someone point to me the issue with the above snippet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm doing it with [DirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

```
$files_in_directory = new DirectoryIterator($path_to_folder);
$c = 0;

foreach($files_in_directory as $file)
{
    // We want only files
    if($file->isDot()) continue;
    if($file->isDir()) continue;
    $c++;
}

var_dump($c);
```

For use as function :

```
function folderlist($directories = array(), $extensions = array())
{
    if(empty($directories))
        return false;

    $result      = array();
    $total_count = 0;
    foreach($directories as $directory)
    {
        $files_in_directory = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
        $c                  = 0;
    
        foreach($files_in_directory as $file)
        {
            // We want only files
            if($file->isDot()) continue;
            if($file->isDir()) continue;
    
            // This is for php < 5.3.6
            $file_extension = pathinfo($file->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
            // If you have php >= 5.3.6 you can use following instead
            // $file_extension = $fileinfo->getExtension()
    
            if(in_array($file_extension, $extensions)){
                $c++;
                $result['directories'][$directory]['files'][$c]['name'] = $file->getFilename();
                $result['directories'][$directory]['files'][$c]['path'] = $file->getPath();
                $result['directories'][$directory]['count']             = $c;
            }     
        }
        $total_count += $c;    
    }

    $result['total_count'] = $total_count;

    return $result;    

}
```

Displaying results based on GET superglobal:

```
if(isset($_GET['album']) && !empty($_GET['album']) && !isset($_GET['listfiles']))
    {
        // We are in directory view mode
        $album = $_GET['album'];
        
        // View all directories and their file count for specified album
        $view_directory = folderlist(array($album), array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'log'));
        
        // Loop the folders and display them with file count
        foreach ($view_directory['directories'] as $folder_name => $folder_files){
        
            $count = $folder_files['count'];
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="files.php?album=' . $folder_name . '&listfiles=1" class="style1">';
            echo '<strong>' . basename($folder_name) . '</strong>';
            echo ' (' . $count . ' files found)';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';  
        
        }
        
        echo "Total Files:". $get_dir_info['total_count'];   
        
    }
    elseif(isset($_GET['album'], $_GET['listfiles']) && !empty($_GET['album']))
    {
        // We are in file view mode for folder
        $album = $_GET['album'];
        
        // View all files in directory
        $view_files = folderlist(array($album), array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'log'));   
        
        echo 'Showing folder content of: <b>'.basename($album).'</b>';
        foreach($view_files['directories'][$album]['files'] as $file)
        {     
            
            $path = $file['path'];
            $name = $file['name'];
            
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="files.php?file=' . $name . '&path=' . $path . '" class="style1">';
            echo '<strong>' . $name . '</strong>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';   
        } 
    }
```

Comment: dear your code is gud but my problem is not solve i want a folder list and each folder show count inside files example foldera(23 files found) folderb (12 file found)

Comment: @user1833487 well from your text i assumed you want 1 folder.
But you can modify code to work with in many folder. Give me a sec.

Comment: hmmm how can i modify this code please can you modify for me.

Comment: @user1833487 updated the code, now theres two loops for display part. One with the folders and how many files are in each of them. And other loop for files in that folder.

Comment: dear i want only folder list example foldera(23 file founds) but your code show jpg files also i dont want jpg file listing i want only folder list and number of file in folder

Comment: @user1833487 remove inner display foreach loop and you will have what you want. I also will update code.

Comment: and i how can i change a path to ./ like this i want all folders in subdirectory

Comment: @user1833487 you mean when you click folder in your page you want to see all folders in that folder?

Comment: no dear know code show Specify path to show folders i dont want specify path i want to change specify path ./ all directory show

Comment: You use this function with $_GET['album'] variable from your URL.
Folder traversing scripts are kind of easy way to get hacked, if you don't do it properly.

Comment: no i dont want click to show all folder i want listing a folder only

Comment: know we put manuly path i dont want manuly i want like example foldera folderb folderc folderd foldere folderf and dir.php if i click the dir file so all folder show auto understand>?

Comment: Yes i understand, what you want is to work with $_GET superglobal to display folder contents.

Comment: yes see my code $startdir = './'; this code show all folders i want like this so how can i do like that

Comment: @user1833487 ok i have no time anymore to tailor this code, but i updated code to be able display any directory you want and files in them, also for strart dir use my function of first enter and set default value.

Comment: i want like that if i open dir.php file than all folderlist show auto example if i Specify path "folder1" and in the folder1 have many folder so all folders list show of specify path

Comment: sorry dear i take a huge time of you but if you have a time today or tommorw so please help me ok thanks in advance

Comment: @user1833487 i really gave you all required examples and code for you to do it. It's just matter of calling on what at specified times. If you play around with that code and display you can get it just as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

This line is still returning the '.' and '..' vars.

```
if (!(array_search($folder,$ignoredDirectory) > -1))
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Try

```
if (!array_search($folder,$ignoredDirectory))
```

EDIT:

Also change this:

```
$ignoredDirectory[] = '.';
$ignoredDirectory[] = '..';
```

to

$ignoredDirectory = array( '.', '..' );

Comment: it should be `if(array_search($folder,$ignoredDirectory) === FALSE)` otherwise it'll return true for `.`

Comment: Sorry, I edited it a second ago, I got the logic wrong. Are you using ===?

Comment: yes i change again but not working same result show again :( please help me

Comment: your code solve a little . dot problm now extra dot is not show but my main problem is folder files calculating worng

Comment: See the answer by @arma. That nails the problem.